Angular + springboot +PKCE redirectUris issue for code retrieval
I have angular as frontend, springboot as backend server implement with spring authorization server for PKCE implementation. I am having issue in redirect_uris to work when the final build is deployed on tomcat. I am using useHash strategy in angular routes. when I add '#' in redirect_uris :http://localhost:8080/#/auth-callback , authorize request to retrieve code is failed with 200 response status, but not code redirection happens.please help with fix for this.

I tried adding '#' character in redirect_uris
no issue in the dev setting, but issue after deploying the build on Tomcat to simulate prod.

SecurityConfig.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${base_url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
                config.addAllowedHeader("*");
                config.addAllowedMethod("*");
                config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
                config.setMaxAge(366000L);
                return config;

            }
        })).exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain jwtFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/test/unprotected", "/api/notices", "/api/contact").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/static/**", "/assets/**", "/favicon.ico", "/images/**", "/*.ttf", // Allow
                                                                                                                            // in
                                                                                                                            // subdirectories
                        "/*.woff", "/*.woff2", "/*.eot", "/*.svg", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/*.js", "/*.css", // Root-level CSS and JS
                        "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()).formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler()))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    LogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            response.sendRedirect(baseUrl);
        };
    }

}

oauth2_registered_client table:

id   client_id   client_id_issued_at client_secret   client_secret_expires_at    client_name client_authentication_methods   authorization_grant_types   redirect_uris   scopes  client_settings token_settings
1 oidc-client 09-08-2024 08:33    $2a$10$gqwXtRsO8JStQpT1gV2SYOC8IEHREA6lWs/KoHGeVGIqO6CaURVda    NULL    OIDC Client client_secret_basic authorization_code  http://localhost:8080/#/    openid  {"requireAuthorizationConsent":false,"requireProofKey":true}    "{""accessTokenFormat"":""REFERENCE"",
""accessTokenTimeToLive"":""PT30M"",
""refreshTokenTimeToLive"":""P30D"",
""reuseRefreshTokens"":true}"

application.yml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
  application:
    name: eazybank
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eazybank
    username: postgres
    password: saral001
    driver-class-name : org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform : org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaque-token:
          introspection-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect
          client-id: oidc-client      # Client ID for introspection
          client-secret: password  # Client Secret for introspection
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 200MB
      max-request-size: 200MB   

springdoc:
  enable-spring-security: true
  show-login-endpoint: true
  show-oauth2-endpoints: true
  
#logginglevel.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE
  pattern:
    console: "%file - %m%n"
    
  
server:
  tomcat:
    max-post-size: 209715200  # 200 MB

        
        


Tokens should not be sent to an Angular app. Using the OAuth2 BFF pattern should be preferred.
